# NVIDIA-SMI has failed

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics

I am using Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and have dual GPU Intel (HD 530)/Nvidia (GTX950). When I was using Ubuntu the first time after installed it, Nvidia drivers were successfully working, but now it doesn't work. I tried to install drivers in both Drivers window and command-line.

Secure boot is disabled.
That didn't work: https://www.murhabazi.com/install-nvidia-driver

`nvidia-smi` output:

> NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.

`nvidia-settings` output:

> ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded
>
> (nvidia-settings:4383): GLib-GObject-CRITICAL **: 22:08:05.795:
> g_object_unref: assertion 'G_IS_OBJECT (object)' failed
>
> ** (nvidia-settings:4383): CRITICAL **: 22:08:05.797: ctk_powermode_new: assertion '(ctrl_target != NULL) && (ctrl_target->h
> != NULL)' failed
>
> ERROR: nvidia-settings could not find the registry key file or the X
> server is
> not accessible. This file should have been installed along with this
> driver at
> /usr/share/nvidia/nvidia-application-profiles-key-documentation. The
> application profiles will continue to work, but values cannot be
> prepopulated or validated, and will not be listed in the help text.
> Please see the README for possible values and descriptions.
>
> ** Message: 22:08:05.828: PRIME: No offloading required. Abort
> ** Message: 22:08:05.828: PRIME: is it supported? no

Answer (score -1):

There are two major types of drivers that can be installed on a Linux system for NVIDIA cards, one is developed by xorg which is open source but doesn't interact with `nvidia-smi` and another one is the official proprietary ones developed by NVIDIA that can interact with `smi`.

I guess you have the xorg one

open a terminal and run `sudo apt install nvidia-detect`, this package checks which drivers can be installed on your system. simply run it with `nvidia-detect` and it'll tell you which package is the most suitable for you to install.

Comment: thank you for the quick response. when i run "sudo apt install nvidia-detect", the output: "E: Unable to locate package nvidia-detect", the other hand i run "nvidia-detect", the output: nvidia-detect: command not found. what should i do in this situation?

Comment: Installing proprietary apps isn't permitted on your computer I guess, open a terminal and run `sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`, you'll see a few lines starting with deb and deb-src, they are links to the repository your system uses to update/install apps, add the word "restricted" to the end of each line so that your OS is allowed to download proprietary nvidia drivers, it will look like `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted`

Comment: unfortunately still the same error and "Settings > About" shows Intel as graphic card.

Comment: Try the terminal command ubuntu-drivers list   , that should already have been installed on your system and will list the possible choices of nvidia drivers, pick the latest or the one that says "tested" or "recommended" (if any one has those words).

Comment: yes, i can see all of them and it was installed on my pc, but i cannot use it.

Comment: The program name is "nvidia-detector" from the ubuntu-drivers-common package.